# I want to download pdf from safari browser

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to download pdf file in flutter, I am using web-view to simply open pdf file in iOS but download option is not coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [url launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67090408/i-want-to-download-pdf-from-safari-browser) and simply save file in case of iOS

```
 launch(Constant.pdfResumeD +resumeList[index].id.toString());
```

I simply used launch keyword and it worked for me